# Convert variable into json path

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables

I have a dynamically changing variable from hash with a joint of a json path.

Example:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        $("#display_content").html(position.hash);
    });
    $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
});
```

How is it posible to turn the `hash` variable into a joint of the json url?

---

**Edit:**

By *joint* i mean a part of a json url: `(position.secondposition.content)` so each part seperated by a `.` is a joint.

Comment: Please elabrote **hash variable into a joint of the json url**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `position[hash]`

So change your code as

```
 $("#display_content").html(position[hash]);
```